# Reading file from variable in Python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, scripting

I am trying read the contents of file through a variable

```
file  = '/home/ec2-user/abc.txt'
paths  = open("file","r+")
print paths.read()
```

But this is not working. I need help; I don't want specify `'abc.txt'` directly.

Comment: `"file"` is a string, not a variable reference. Think about that for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to remove the quotes around `"file"`:

```
paths = open(file,"r+")
```

When you're calling something using the value of a variable, you shouldn't quote the variable.

Second, if you don't want to hard code the path to `file`, you'll need to ask the user for it:

```
file = raw_input("Please enter the full path to the file: ")
```